# Core-UI React CMultiSelect reset not working

Tags: reactjs, typescript, core-ui

I am trying to reset Core UI ReactJS CMultiSelect component with Reset button. I have used setState method to reset the value. As soon as I click on the reset button, the state value changes, but immediately onChange method of CMultiSelect is called and the existing value is retained.
Below is the code snippet I'm trying.

```
import React from 'react'
import { CRow, CMultiSelect, CFormInput, CButton } from '@coreui/react-pro'
class TestForm extends React.Component<{}, { textVal: string; dropdownVal: string[] }> {
  constructor(props: any) {
    super(props)
    this.state = { textVal: '123', dropdownVal: [] }
  }
  setTextVal(newVal: string) {
    this.setState({ textVal: newVal })
  }
  setTest(newVal: string[]) {
    this.setState({ dropdownVal: newVal })
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row m-5">
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <CFormInput
            type="text"
            value={this.state.textVal}
            onChange={(evt) => {
              this.setTextVal(evt.target.value)
            }}
          ></CFormInput>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <CMultiSelect
            multiple={false}
            options={[
              {
                value: '1',
                text: '1',
                selected: this.state.dropdownVal.indexOf('1') >= 0,
              },
              {
                value: '2',
                text: '2',
                selected: this.state.dropdownVal.indexOf('2') >= 0,
              },
              {
                value: '3',
                text: '3',
                selected: this.state.dropdownVal.indexOf('3') >= 0,
              },
            ]}
            onChange={(val) => {
              console.log('on change called', val)
              this.setTest(
                val.map((x) => {
                  return x.value.toString()
                }),
              )
            }}
          ></CMultiSelect>
        </div>
        <div className="col-sm-6">
          <CButton
            className="mt-3"
            type="reset"
            value="Reset"
            onClick={() => {
              this.setTest([])
              this.setTextVal('')
            }}
          >
            Reset
          </CButton>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default TestForm
```

When I hit the reset button, value of the text field resets, but not the multi-select dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

try calling the reset method on the component instance. You can do this by saving a reference to the CMultiSelect instance in your component's state, and then calling the reset method on that instance in your reset handler.

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  state = {
    select: null,
  };

  handleReset = () => {
    this.state.select.reset();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <CMultiSelect
          ref={(select) => this.setState({ select })}
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. 
When I tried setting CMultiSelect reference to state, got the following error. 
**Uncaught Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.**